# Oracle - Oracle function to get before and after a character

Tags: oracle, substring

I am having a values in a column like below

```
"2016/01"
"2016 / 02"
"2016 /03"
"2016/ 04"
```

I would basically need to write a oracle query to standardize it to yyyy / mm format.

I am using the below code but its not working

```
ltrim(rtrim(NVL(SUBSTR(month, 0, INSTR(month, '/')-1), month))) ||' / '|| ltrim(rtrim(NVL(SUBSTR(month, 0, INSTR(month, '/')+1), month))) AS month1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR(month,1,4),'/'),SUBSTR(month,(LENGTH(month)-1),2))
```